# How to loop the array with different object names, can we use regular expression in reactJS to loop all different named objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, regex, loops

In JSON under items I have multiple CardValues array with same pattern of response  have different name(CardValues_1......CardValues_4)I want to foreach all the cardValues and access 'elements' object for all 4 .

I am trying to do regular expression for CardValues to loop all 4, the regexp is not working. is there any other way to loop of different name.

```js
const {
               CardValues_1,
               CardValues_2,
               CardValues_3,
               CardCardValues_4,
               CardTitle,
               actionCardValues_1,
               actionCardValues_2,
               actionCardValues_3
            } = items


            const CardValues = items./^CardValues/.map(values =>
               journeyCard(values))
```

```html
JSON:
Sample json for of the cardValues , it repeats for all 4 with different name
 "CardValues_1": {
      "title": "",
      "description": "",
      "model": "",
      "elements": {
        "imgPath": {
          "title": "Image Path",
          "dataType": "string",
          "value": "",
          ":type": "string"
        },
        "description": {
          "title": "Description",
          "paragraphs": [
            ""
          ],
          "dataType": "string",
          ":type": "text/html"
        },
        "footerTitle": {
          "title": "",
          "dataType": "string",
          "value": "",
          ":type": "string"
        },
        "href": {
          "title": "Href",
          "dataType": "string",
          "value": "",
          ":type": "string"
        },
        "button": {
          "title": "button",
          "dataType": "boolean",
          "value": false,
          ":type": "boolean"
        },
        "link": {
          "title": "link",
          "dataType": "boolean",
          "value": true,
          ":type": "boolean"
        },
        
      },
     
      ]
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter, over keys, that match to your regular expression

```js
const items = {
               CardValues_1: 1,
               CardValues_2: 2,
               CardValues_3: 3,
               CardCardValues_4: 4,
               CardTitle: 5,
               actionCardValues_1: 6,
               actionCardValues_2: 7,
               actionCardValues_3: 8
            }

console.log(
    Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(items)
    .filter(([key, value]) => key.match(/^CardValues/)))
);
```